# MS Access: Delete all records if at least once a condition occurs

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to, let's say, in a table of phones and their ratings delete all records of a given phone if at least once it received a rating lower than specified?

```
Company  Rating
Samsung      5
Samsung      2
```

In that example, if I wanted to get rid of phones rated at least once lower than 3, I would have to delete all records that have "Samsung" in it.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Try to figure it out and we will help.PS> show us your schema.

Comment: Is it doable in QBE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to work through this problem... (Some would do this in SQL code, as you see in WolfgangK's answer, but I will use the visual query builder, since that is probably going to be easier for you to understand as you are starting out.)

First, here is an example data set. For our problem, we want to delete the records for any phone company with a rating of 3 or less. In this list, we want to delete all the records for LG, even though only one of them has a rating of 3.

[image]

If we only wanted to delete the records that have a rating of 3 or less, that would be easy. We would just do it with a delete query like this:

[image]

But in your case, you want to delete ALL the records for that company, even if only SOME match the criteria. No problem, just a little more complex. We need to start by identifying the companies that meet the criteria. Let's create a new query called **qryBadReviews**:

It is very similar to our delete query, but also lists the company name in the results. (We could also group it, if we wanted to only see the company name listed once.)

[image]

[image]

Now, the next step is to create our delete query that links to the bad reviews query with a matching company name. Simple enough, but then we have a problem:

[image]

To fix this, you simply need to change the Unique Records property to `Yes` in your query, and then it should run for you.

[image]

[image]

And the resulting data set:

[image]

Sorry, LG, it was just an example! I do like your phones.  :-)

Comment: You are welcome! If you like it, feel free to upvote it and mark as the accepted answer.  :-)

Comment: I can't yet because of rep. Though if I ever get there I will remember to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a subquery for this, for example:

```
DELETE * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable AS tmp WHERE Company = YourTable.Company AND Rating < 3)
```